# Android Studio 3.4 for Windows 10 - can't find the Device File Explorer

Tags: android, android-studio

Good evening,

I looked everywhere but I still can't find Device File Explorer (DFE).

- The device is connected and recognized by ADB in the DOS prompt
- The device has the "Debug USB" option enabled and it's in "File Transfer" USB mode
- In Android Studio there's no DFE icon in the bottom right corner
- In the "View > Tool Windows" menu there's nothing useful
- In the "Tools" menu there's nothing useful

How can I find it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your "View > Tool Windows" menu and add it to your question? Also, is your open project an Android app project, or a generic Java project? In an Android app project, Device File Explorer should appear in that menu, about two-thirds of the way down from the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall, reinstall and open a Cordova project (platforms/android/app) and updating Gradle stuff did the trick, now I can see Device File Explorer, thank you guys!

Answer (score 2):

Go to file > Project Structure > module
inside module click on add icon and select Android and click OK

This will add the Device file explorer in the android studio

Answer (score 1):

This is how it should look alike:

[image: screenshot]

In case that button should be missing, the installation might be broken.

Comment: You have WAY more Tool Windows than I do!  How do you turn those on?

Comment: Not really--Device File Explorer (and many others) were MISSING from my menu because (as it turned out) the Android framework wasn't configured in my project even though I've been doing Flutter development for weeks.

Comment: @PeteAlvin Sorry, did not know that this menu depends on the project configuration, which appear to be a useful hint for others with the same problem.

Comment: These menu items were all missing for me - but I opened a random folder on my machine as the "project". So I just created a new android project, default settings, and it downloaded and installed all the gradle stuff. Once that built, all those menu items appeared.